# Attach image.png to an embed Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Is there are any way to Attach Image from file to Discord.py embed "thumbnail"?

```
embed.set_thumbnail(url=" Attached image")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
file = discord.File("file path", filename="image.png")
embed = discord.Embed()
embed.set_thumbnail(url="attachment://image.png")
await messagable.send(file=file, embed=embed)
```